# How to make image responsive for mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used two columns in my code one for image and other for the description of that image. When I execute my site as mobile view then my image shows only half of it. And when I use col-sm-6 for both, the height of both increases too much and it shows an extra gap between its lower and current container. I also tried 'max-width:100%;' and 'height:auto;' but then it's beside contents shows at the bottom of that image.

Note: when I use col-sm-5 for both, the left side area of page lefts empty.

HTML

```
<section id="expertise" class="expert">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-img" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 section">
        <h2 class="title">Responsive</h2>
        <div class="item">
          <p>
            Description of that image goes here
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.expert {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.expert p {
  line-height: 200%;
}

.expert .bg-img {
  background-image: url(../images/web.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.expert .bg-img:after {
  display: none;
}

.expert .section {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

JS

```
var h = $('.expert').height();
  $('.expert .col-sm-6 div').height(function (index, height) {
    return (h);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `background-image` for images, so `max-width:100%` will do nothing...use `background-size: cover`...

Also you will need to change your jQuery to calculate `height()`...

```
var h = $('.expert .col-sm-5').height();
$('.expert .col-sm-6 div').height(function(index, height) {
  return (h);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because class img-responsive is to be given to the image containing tag

```
.expert .bg-img {
  background-image: url(../images/web.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position:left;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Try changing it like this